# Linq2Sql How to write outer join query?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have following SQL tables.

**ImportantMessages**

impID

Message

**ImportantMessageUsers**

imuID

imuUserID

imuImpID

I want to write a Linq2Sql query so that it returns any rows from ImportantMessages
that does not have a record in ImportantMessagesUsers.

Matchiing fields are
impID ----- imuImpID

Assume imuUserID of 6

Answer (score 2):

It would be just as simple as

```
var messages = context.ImportantMessages.Where(x => x.ImportantMessageUsers.Count() == 0);
```

**EDIT**

I think I have understood the problem well, you have to get all messages from ImportantMessages table without any row in ImportantMessageUsers table, which is connected with a foreign key ImportantMessagesUsers.imuImpID = ImportantMessages.impID.

Please check if you have a foreign key between these tables and then delete these tables from Linq context designer and add them again - the foreign key should be visible between them thus creating such properties as ImportantMessages.ImportantMessageUsers which is as IEnumerable of type ImportantMessageUser allowing to use expressions like x.ImportantMessageUsers.Count() == 0.

**EDIT2**

When user Id must be filtered, this lambda expression should do the trick:

```
var messages = context.ImportantMessages.Where(x => x.ImportantMessageUsers.Where(y => y.imuUserID == 6).Count() == 0);
```

Using lambda over LINQ notation is only a matter of preference, yet when multiple joins aren't required, lambda is generally more intuitive to use.

Comment: I don't think yo unerstand the question.

Comment: I think that this answer is right...It's returns all the rows in context.ImportantMessages that the numbers of rows related in importantMessageUsers is 0. But it only works if there is a foreign key from importantMessageUsers to ImportantMessages. (you should have this FK)

Comment: I see I need to add the relationship.

Comment: Yes, if the relationship is in the Database, the designer will add it for you when you drag the tables into it.

Comment: I still don't see how the user is taken into account here. A user may have multiple messages. The usres tble is not for one user??

Answer (score 1):

Check out DefaultIfEmpty().

Here's an example from one of my old SO questions:

[LINQ to SQL - How to add a where clause to a left join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395069/linq-to-sql-how-to-add-a-where-clause-to-a-left-join)

```
var z = 
    from im in importantMessages
    join imu in importantMessageUsers
        on new { im.impID,  imuUserID = 7 } equals 
        new { imu.imuImpID, imu.imuUserID  }
    into imJoin
    from ij in imJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where ij.imuImpID == null
    select new
    {
        im.Message
        ...
```

Comment: My problem is even after reading some documentation I cannot work it out??

Comment: You have not taken the userID into account.

Comment: I added a sample.  Do you have LinqPad?  Much easier to work through using it as a scratchpad.  There's a free version.

Comment: I am getting syntax erros with this in LinqPad

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me.

```
var qry = from imp in ImportantMessages
where !(from imu in ImportantMessagesUsers where imu.ImuUsrID == 6 select imu.ImuImpID).Contains(imp.ImpID)
select imp;
```